# Starting Hadoop h2o IO error sending batch UDP bytes

Tags: h2o

When starting Hadoop h2o (YARN h2o) with the following command:

```
hadoop jar ./h2o-3.18.0.4-cdh5.13/h2odriver.jar -nodes 10 -mapperXmx 5g   -output junk/tmp1
```

I seem to sometimes get an issue bringing up the h2o cluster.  This is the error I see on console:

```
ERROR: Timed out waiting for H2O cluster to come up (120 seconds)
ERROR: (Try specifying the -timeout option to increase the waiting time limit)
Attempting to clean up hadoop job...
Killed.
```

This is the error I see in YARN logs:

```
03-09 14:50:35.118 x.x.x.56:54321    37628  #49:54321 ERRR: Got IO error when sending batch UDP bytes: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to try:

- Increase the timeout with the -timeout option
- After increasing the timeout, does it still work sometimes and not other times?  If yes, then you may have a host-level networking issue within your hadoop cluster.
- Get `yarn logs -applicationId nnn` and look at which of the hosts has the issue.  Is there a pattern in the IP address you can spot?